# Calculate population standard deviation of a column

Tags: r

I want to know the standard deviation of every column i have in a data frame.
Right now i'm using the formula

```
apply(df,2,sd)
```

But it's showing me the sample standard deviation, what is the way to find the population standard deviation in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

We can define the calculation for population standard deviation:

```
sd.p=function(x){sd(x)*sqrt((length(x)-1)/length(x))}
# From  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66349386/6851825
```

And then use your formulation:

```
apply(mtcars,2,sd.p)
        mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs 
  5.9320296   1.7577951 121.9867814  67.4830708   0.5262581   0.9630477   1.7588006   0.4960784 
         am        gear        carb 
  0.4911323   0.7261844   1.5897622
```

From other answers in that question it looks like there is not a built-in function for this in base R, but a number of packages include a function to that effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59120744/6851825